# Inner div not expanding with Outer div

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular application which included UI-Bootstrap and I have an issue with responsiveness.

Index.html:

```
<body>
    <div ng-include="'partials/common/loginHeader.html'" ng-show="!userInfo"></div> 
    <div ng-include="'partials/common/userHeader.html'" ng-show="userInfo"></div> 

    <div class="main">
        <div class="main-inner">
            <div class="container" ui-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div ng-include="'partials/common/footer.html'"></div>--> <!-- footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Partial view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="widget widget-nopad">
        <div class="widget-header">...Content inside DIV...</div>
        <div class="widget-content">...Content inside DIV...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="widget>...Content inside DIV...</div>
        <div class="widget widget-table action-table">
            <div class="widget-header">...Content inside DIV...</div>
            <div class="widget-content">...Content inside DIV...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am just showing the DIV structure in my partial view. The webpage looks normal in normal laptop view. But with increase in height and width of the screen, the content inside the `<div class="row">` remains same and leaves a huge space outside it blank.
[image]

How can i alter the `<div class="row">` so that it will stretch and make use of the blank space inside `<div class="main">`?

I will add more pictures to get a clear understanding of DIV's (DIV's have been highlighted in blue)

Div.main-inner :

[image]

Div.row :

[image]

In normal laptop resolution :

[image]

Comment: That is because bootstrap "container" has fixed width for media, use "container-fluid" class for full width

Comment: That seem to have stretched the width of Div.row. but the content inside seem to have been totally misplaced. Maybe because of <div class="span">

Comment: Is there something that can be done to set the span to be responsive and change according to the size of the row?

Comment: Whats happening is , after I changed the container to fluid, the content inside keeps pushed to the left. The more I zoom out, the more the content keeps going to the left while the headers remain centered.

Comment: Check the screenshot to get a clear picture :
http://i.imgur.com/3sAkadg.jpg

Comment: Is there something that can be done to set the span to be responsive and change according to the size of the row? **Seems like you are using old version of bootstrap, checkout version 3, which provide responsive layout**
Whats happening is , after I changed the container to fluid, the content inside keeps pushed to the left. The more I zoom out, the more the content keeps going to the left while the headers remain centered. **That seems like you have to set margin auto, for header I think you haven't posted code of it**

Comment: Im using UI-Angular-Bootstrap.... Can we use Bootstrap to modify angular elements?